# Há "problemas" usar jQuery's pequenos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, desempenho

Por exemplo, algumas partes de um site, não posso mexer totalmente no HTML, pôs a plataforma bloqueia por "segurança" e não deixa modificar, então uso jQuery/JavaScript pra fazer a modificação que necessito. Isso interfere no desempenho do site? Muito ou pouco?

Exemplo de um código que usei agora, só pra inserir uma imagem:

```
$j('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/UgaMSoE.png" style="max-width: 1.5rem;"/>').insertBefore('section#desejos .mywish__header a svg');
```

Uso códigos assim de vez em quando (Não muitos, somente de vez em quando mesmo), quando não da pra modificar algo que preciso. Isso influência MUITO no desempenho do site?

Tem algum problema ficar usando códigos "pequenos" em jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Pense q tudo q você está fazendo com jQuery, está sendo convertido para javascript por trás dos panos. O uso dele e recomendável para deixar o código menor e mais limpo em projetos médios e grandes. Mas adicionar uma biblioteca inteira para não usar uma ou duas linhas de javascript puro no seu projeto, além de uma má pratica, passa a ser preguiça. Pois não seria difícil encontrar o mesmo código na internet em javascript puro!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, há problemas de SEO. Hoje tempo de carga conta para a página ser bem classificada em mecanismo de busca.

Isto por si só já deveria ser algo para se pensar em usar jQuery. Ainda mais para fazer uma única linha para fazer algo que dá para fazer igual ou mais simples sem jQuery.

Muito não interfere no desempenho geral, mas interfere.

O único jeito de saber se vale para o seu caso é fazer e testar.

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar sem medo. Isto não vai influenciar no desempenho, há apenas uma sobrecarga inicial no primeiro carregamento, onde o arquivo *Javascript* do *jQuery* que vai ser carregado. Após isto, o arquivo já estará em cache e praticamente haverá custo 0 de *download*.

Certifique-se apenas de em produção utilizar arquivos minificados, assim reduzindo a banda necessária para *download* destes arquivos.

Em casos onde fará apenas uma pequena alteração via *jQuery*, tente utilizar *Javascript* puro em vez de carregar o *jQuery* apenas para inserir um conteúdo na página por exemplo.

Abaixo um código de inserção de *HTML* na página com javascript puro:

```
var newItem = document.createElement("LI");       // Create a <li> node
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");  // Create a text node
newItem.appendChild(textnode);                    // Append the text to <li>

var list = document.getElementById("myList");    // Get the <ul> element to insert a new node
list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);  // Insert <li> before the first child of <ul>
```

Este exemplo foi retirado do [site da W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp):

** **Editado** **

Em questão de *SEO*, você deve colocar arquivos *Javascript* no final da página para evitar que o carregamento do arquivo trave a página, assim gerando atraso no carregamento do site. Você inclusive pode pedir uma análise ao Google para checar o site e ter algumas instruções para melhorá-lo. [Clicando aqui](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) você vai para o site de análise do *Google*.

Comment: No caso, usar o codigo no body e não no heady, certo? Pro SEO.

Comment: É melhor mesmo usar o JavaScript puro, mesmo sendo "maior" do que usar o JQuery?

Comment: Isto não é verdade, jQuery faz um estrago na performance geral. Se essa performance é necessária ou não é outra estória, em geral não é. Mas isso pode ser mensurado.

Comment: Lucas, correto, utilizar no final antes do fechamento do body. Sobre o que o bigown disse, existe um overhead no uso do jQuery, pois ele é o javascript encapsulado, de forma que "utilizamos atalhos" para na verdade, ser executado um código de javascript puro. Atualmente, o overhead que gera eu não me preocuparia, praticamente todos os sites hoje pussem libs em javascript e nem por isso percebemos tal efeito. Um site para comparar código javascript puro vs jquery seria o seguinte: https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/22

Comment: Se quase 1000x mais lento não importa, então está bom.

Comment: bigown, claro que é importante, mas esses testes são executados para milhões de execuções. Neste ambiente, sem dúvida javascript puro, mas quando você tem pequenas interações, para o humano é imperceptível.